# multi-valued natural log

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Not a difficult question I think, yet I want to have your input on this. Since $ln(a)=ln|a| + i*arg(a)$ we can see that the $ln$ is multi-valued, if we don't restrict the argument. So if we want to solve $b^x=a$, we arrive at $x=ln(a)$/$ln(b)$ but both ln's are multi-valued. Does this mean we have two parameters in the answer? One parameter (say $n$) for the "multiples" for $ln(a)$ and another parameter (say $k$) for $ln(b)$? Input appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Check a simple case like $2^x=3$. Is the equation satisfied by $x=\dfrac{\log3+i(\arg3+2n\pi)}{\log2+i(\arg2+2k\pi)}$ for any choice of $(n,k)\in\Bbb Z^2$?

Comment: To my understanding...yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general we  define $b^x$ as $\exp(x \log b)$. This is multivalued because $\log$ is multivalued.  Now there's a problem with an equation $b^x = a$ where the left side is multivalued.  Presumably this is supposed to mean that $a$ is one of the values of $b^x$, i.e. $a = \exp(x (\text{Log }b + 2 \pi i m))$ where $\text{Log } b$ is one of the values of $\log b$ and $m$ is an arbitrary integer.  Now $a = \exp(\log a)$: again any of the values of $\log a$ will work.  So we have
$$ \exp(\log a) = \exp(x \log b) = \exp(x (\text{Log }b + 2 \pi i m))$$
Now notice that because of the periodicity of $\exp$, $\exp(s) = \exp(t)$ means $s - t$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi i$.
Thus, if $\text{Log }a$ is one of the values of $\log a$,
$$ \text{Log }a + 2 \pi i n = x (\text{Log }b + 2 \pi i m)$$
and so indeed, we get a two-parameter family of solutions

$$ x = \frac{\text{Log }a + 2 \pi i n}{\text{Log }b  + 2 \pi i m} $$
where $n$ and $m$ are integers.  But again there's a caveat: for these values of $x$, $a$ is one of the values of $b^x$.

Comment: So I was right in my observation that two parameters are needed. All solutions are complex with the exception of that one real solution $ln(a)$/$ln(b)$. One reason I am asking this, is because in the real world, and exponential equation like $1^x=2$ has no solution but in the complex world, it does, and in fact there are many.